# Speed up vector-creation

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create a vector with all numbers within ranges defined in a table. For example the rows 23:25 and 34:39 shall become the single vector `c(23, 24, 25, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39)`

The MWE below does this, but is way too slow. I need to do it for n.rows of 15,000,000 or higher.

`row.references` is the input. `row.references.long` is the wanted output.

What is a better code to do this?

```
library(data.table)
# Create example data
n.rows <- 1000
row.references <- data.table(start.number=floor(runif(n=n.rows, min=1, max=100)), steps=floor(runif(n=n.rows, min=1, max=50)))
row.references[, end.number:=start.number+steps]
row.references[, steps:=NULL]
row.references.long <- NULL
# The too-slow code
for (i in 1:nrow(row.references)) {
  row.references.long <- rbind(row.references.long, data.table(row.references[i, start.number]:row.references[i, end.number]))
}
```

I suppose `data.table` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not grow an object in a loop. Pre-allocate. Here is a more efficient version of your loop:

```
res <- do.call(c, mapply(seq, 
                        row.references[["start.number"]], 
                        row.references[["end.number"]], 
                        MoreArgs = list(by = 1)))
all.equal(res, row.references.long[[1]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Here is another option. Benchmark to see if it is faster.

```
row.references[, lengths := end.number - start.number + 1]
res <- row.references[, .(V1 = rep(as.integer(start.number) - 1L, times = lengths))]
res[, V1 := V1 + seq_along(V1), 
    by = rep(seq_len(nrow(row.references)), row.references[["lengths"]])]
all.equal(res, row.references.long)
#[1] TRUE
```

However, I would do this in compiled code, i.e., with Rcpp.

Comment: Why not `unlist(mapply(":", row.references$start.number, row.references$end.number), use.names = FALSE)`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Sure, why not.

Comment: I suspect that `unlist` would be faster than `do.call(c, ...)`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto it is indeed faster, see the benchmark in my answer

Comment: @Jaap, it won't scale as well. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

For some reason, this still strikes me as overthinking things. I'm not sure if there's a big disadvantage to using `by = 1:nrow(indt)`, but that gives me good performance.

My suggestion for "data.table" would simply be:

```
row.references[, list(V1 = start.number:end.number), 
               by = 1:nrow(row.references)]$V1
```

And for base R, would be:

```
unlist(mapply(":", row.references$start.number, row.references$end.number), 
         use.names = FALSE)
```

This latter one is similar to Roland's approach, but just uses `:` and `unlist` instead of `do.call(c, ...)`

---

#### Benchmarks

Here's your sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
n.rows <- 1000
row.references <- data.table(start.number=floor(runif(n=n.rows, min=1, max=100)), 
                             steps=floor(runif(n=n.rows, min=1, max=50)))
row.references[, end.number:=start.number+steps]
row.references[, steps:=NULL]
```

Here are a few functions to try out:

```
AM1 <- function() {
  unlist(mapply(":", row.references$start.number, row.references$end.number), 
         use.names = FALSE)
}

AM2 <- function() {
  row.references[, list(V1 = start.number:end.number), 
                 by = 1:nrow(row.references)]$V1
}

roland1 <- function() {
  do.call(c, mapply(seq, 
                    row.references[["start.number"]], 
                    row.references[["end.number"]], 
                    MoreArgs = list(by = 1)))
}

roland2 <- function(indt = copy(row.references)) {
  indt[, lengths := end.number - start.number + 1]
  res <- indt[, .(V1 = rep(as.integer(start.number) - 1L, times = lengths))]
  res[, V1 := V1 + seq_along(V1), 
      by = rep(seq_len(nrow(indt)), indt[["lengths"]])]$V1
}

jaap <- function(indt = copy(row.references)) {
  indt[, `:=` (idx=.I)][, .(var = seq(start.number,end.number)), by = idx]$var
}
```

Check that they are all equal:

```
sapply(c(quote(AM2()), quote(roland1()), quote(roland2()), quote(jaap())), 
       function(x) all.equal(AM1(), eval(x)))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Now, make some bigger data:

```
# Make the data bigger -- 2.5 million rows
row.references <- rbindlist(replicate(2500, row.references, FALSE))
dim(row.references)
```

Test out the timings:

```
system.time(AM1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   6.936   0.000   6.845 

system.time(AM2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.480   0.212   2.800 

system.time(roland1())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  64.932   0.000  63.525 

system.time(roland2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.488   0.000   2.434 

system.time(jaap())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  14.068   0.000  13.643
```

It seems like `roland2` and `AM2` are viable alternatives. Even if this "microbenchmark" is a bit off, I feel `AM2` trumps in readability:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(AM2(), roland2(), times = 20)
# Unit: seconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#       AM2() 2.202286 2.236027 2.323602 2.320230 2.394856 2.477074    20
#   roland2() 2.314997 2.428790 2.502338 2.477764 2.589151 2.700195    20
```

Comment: Nice! I should have been able to come up with the *AM2*-solution as well :-( (but obviously didn't)

Comment: @Ananda Congrats for getting 100K :-) Welcome to the 100kers list.

Answer (score 4):

As @Roland mentioned, there is no need for a for-loop. You can do this entirely in *data.table* with the help of an index (`idx`) column:

```
set.seed(12)
row.ref <- data.table(start.number=floor(runif(n=n.rows, min=1, max=100)),
                      steps=floor(runif(n=n.rows, min=1, max=50)))
row.ref[, `:=` (end.number=start.number+steps, idx=.I)]

row.ref.l <- row.ref[, .(var = seq(start.number,end.number)), by = idx][, idx:=NULL]
```

which results in:

```
> head(row.ref,3)
   start.number steps end.number idx
1:            7     3         10   1
2:           81     8         89   2
3:           94    40        134   3

> head(row.ref.l,15)
    var
 1:   7
 2:   8
 3:   9
 4:  10
 5:  81
 6:  82
 7:  83
 8:  84
 9:  85
10:  86
11:  87
12:  88
13:  89
14:  94
15:  95
```

---

A benchmark of the several proposed solutions:

```
microbenchmark(jaap = row.references[, .(var = seq(start.number,end.number)), by = idx],
               roland1 = do.call(c, mapply(seq,row.references[["start.number"]],row.references[["end.number"]],MoreArgs = list(by = 1))),
               roland2 = row.references[, lengths := end.number - start.number + 1][, .(V1 = rep(as.integer(start.number) - 1L, times = lengths))][, V1 := V1 + seq_along(V1), by = rep(seq_len(nrow(row.references)), row.references[["lengths"]])],
               ananda = data.table(unlist(mapply(":", row.references$start.number, row.references$end.number), use.names = FALSE)),
               times = 100, unit = "relative")
```

which gives:

```
Unit: relative
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval  cld
    jaap  5.517431  5.358356  5.168787  5.183828  5.164292 2.157907   100   c 
 roland1 19.023350 18.029892 16.897831 17.475423 17.111857 5.682705   100    d
 roland2  2.051662  2.015041  1.912261  1.964078  1.957416 1.277075   100  b  
  ananda  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100 a
```

Comment: It's important to note that this is still a loop with `nrow(row.ref)` calls to an R function (with all the overhead of an interpreted language).

Answer (score 1):

For one way to avoid explicit iteration, create a sequence spanning the entire range (use a numeric vector to avoid integer overflow), then correct elements by the offset required to make the elements corresponding to the start of each sequence, equal to the start of the sequence.

```
f <- function(start, step) {
    res <- seq(1, sum(step + 1), by=1)
    offset <- start -  c(0, cumsum(step + 1)[-length(step)]) - 1L
    res + rep(offset, step + 1)
}
```

Comment: On a similar note (exchanging a `lapply` for less code): `steps = abs(start - stop) + 1; rep(start, steps) + sequence(steps) - 1`

Comment: @alexis_laz I didn't know about `sequence()`; it seems like a nice, reasonably performant solution, even if it involves iteration (`lapply`) under the hood.